# standard.StandardAnalyzer not found in lucene 4.7.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lucene, standardanalyzer

I'm newbies to lucene. i'm trying to do the tutorial here http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html

The site is importing:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
```

however, on my intellij, I can't find any standard within analysis package. So, I can't really use StandardAnalyzer.

do i need to use different jar? the jar i'm using is

```
lucene-core-4.7.0.jar
```

which I imported from

```
lucene-4.7.0/core
```

directory.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, apparaently, i need to add another jar from

```
lucene-4.7.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.7.0.jar
```

Comment: That is it, good chance you'll also end up needing `lucene-queryparser-4.7.0.jar`.